# Asp.net page still flickers with UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have a page which contains a Listview,. The ItemTemplate will contain many Checkboxes for each returned value from it's datasource. These Checkboxes has a OnCheckedChanged function and when a user selects the checkbox, the page flickers...I have investigated UpdatePanels, but to no avail. Also, this page contains a MasterPage.

Code:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ListView ID="lvTypes" runat="server" DataSourceID="XXX" GroupItemCount="4">
           <ItemTemplate>
             <td style="background-color: #4b6c9e;" align="left">
                 <asp:CheckBox ID="Type" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Type") %>'  ForeColor="White"  OnCheckedChanged="chk_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="myCheck" Font-Size="45px" />
             </td>
                ...
                ...
                ...
```

Obviously, I am not grasping the concept of the UpdatePanel. Can you direct me on how to implement this for this scenario"?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `UpdateMode = "Conditional"` it'll do a partial refresh.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" UpdateMode = "Conditional" runat="server">
```

Read [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel(v=vs.110).aspx) to get an idea of the `UpdatePanel` control.

And, also have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386454(v=vs.100).aspx) comprehensive explanation in MSDN

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will look into the links that you provided.